# Raise Abort in Jenkins Job from Batch script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job, which do Git syncs and build the source code.

I added and created a "Post build task" option.

In 'post build task', I am searching for keyword "TIMEOUT:" in console output (this part is done) and want to declare job as Failed and Aborted if keyword matches.

How can I raise / declare the Job as Aborted from batch script if keyword matches. Something like `echo ABORT`?

Comment: Have you tried: `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'` in your Post build task?

Comment: @Sagar is `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'` a batch script?

Comment: Nope. Its Jenkins Property

Comment: @Sagar 'currentBuild.result' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 1):

you can simply exit the flow and raise the error code that you want:

```
echo "Timeout detected!"
exit 1
```

Jenkins should detect the error and set-up the build as failed.

The error code must be between 1 and 255. You can chose whatever your want, just be aware that some code are reserved:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html#EXITCODESREF

You can also consider using the time-out plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin

And another option is to build a query to `BUILD ID URL/stop`. Which is exactly what is done when you manually abort a build.

```
echo "Timeout detected!"
curl yourjenkins/job_name/11/stop
```

Comment: i don't want to make build failed. i want to make it as Aborted.

Comment: You can use a dedicated plugin for that. Or you can send a request to yourbuildurl/stop. It will abort your build.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier if you want mark it as "FAIL"

Just exit 1 will do that.

It is tricky to achieve "Abort" from post build task plugin, it is much easier to use Groovy post build plugin.

The groovy post build provide rich functions to help you.

Such as match function:

```
def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Total time: (.*)\$")
if(matcher?.matches()) {
    manager.addShortText(matcher.group(1), "grey", "white", "0px", "white")
}
```

Abort function:

```
  def executor = build.executor ?: build.oneOffExecutor;
  if (executor != null){
      executor.interrupt(Result.ABORTED)
  }
```

Br,

Tim

Comment: `def matcher = manager.getLogMatcher(".*Building remotely.*")
if(matcher?.matches()) {
 def executor = build.executor ?: build.oneOffExecutor;
            if (executor != null){
             executor.interrupt(Result.ABORTED)
        }
}`
Is this right way to do? i am getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: try use manager.build instead of build, for detail, pls ref this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin